# AJAX request being sent twice with ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activeadmin

I am sending a request using :remote => true, but each time I click on the request it sends it twice?

I have tried removing //require jquery from application.js, it solves this problem but then jQuery requests are not sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that jquery-ujs included twice and there are two events that fired on click. Check all included js files for duplicates.

Comment: ActiveAdmin also adds jquery files in its gem, so that is the case

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had required both jquery and jquery-ujs.
Deleting the latter, resolved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Check if there any JavaScript click event with ajax binded to the element.